# The square-integrability of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\xi_k \langle e_k,h\rangle,\ h\in H$

Tags: probability

Assume that $H$ is a separable Hilbert space and $\{e_k\}$ is an orthonormal and complete basis of $H$.

$\{\xi_k\}$ is a sequence of normal Gaussian random variables that are independent.

It seems that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\xi_k \langle e_k,h\rangle,\ h\in H$ is square-integrable, but I am not sure how to prove. Who can give me some hints?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I changed $< e_k,h>$ to $\langle e_k,h\rangle$.  That is standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is equivalent to ask whether for a square summable sequence $(a_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ the random variable 
$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}a_k\xi_k$ is square integrable or not, where $\xi_k\sim\mathcal N(m_k,\sigma_k^2)$. First of all we have to check the almost sure convergence of the series. Looking at the characteristic functions, necessary conditions are the convergence of the series $\sum_k m_ka_k$ and 
$\sum_k a_k^2\sigma_k^2$. With these conditions, we can bound the $\mathbb L^2$-norm of the $N$-th partial sum uniformly with respect to $N$ and conclude by Fatou's lemma.